# Add points to 3D-Function using plot3d in Maxima

Tags: maxima, plot3d

I'm plotting the function x^3 + 5*x*y - y^2 in Maxima.

plot3d([x^3+5*x*y - y^2,[x,-2,12],[y,-2,12]]);

[The function in 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Ojh.png)

What I would like to do is add a point at (0,0,0) to the graph.

plot3d([0,0,0],[x,-2,12],[y,-2,12]);

runs, but does not actually show anything (???). And in any case,

plot3d([[x^3+5*x*y - y^2,[x,-2,12],[y,-2,12]],
[[0,0,0] ,[x,-2,12],[y,-2,12]]]);

gives an error (plot3d: argument must be a list of three expressions;).

Does anyone have an idea how this might work?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
draw3d(explicit(x^3+5*x*y - y^2, x, -2, 12, y, -2, 12),
    point_size = 4, point_type = 7,
    points([[0, 0, 0]]));
```

[image: maxima figure]